# What is importlib.util in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-scanner, python-importlib

I am trying to `pip install importlib` with python 3.6, but I get an Import Error saying: 'NO Module named "importlib.util"'. This also comes up when I try to `pip install imagescanner`, which is my real intention. Building an App that connects to Image Scanner Devices, but that's another problem...
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Seems to me that `importlib` is built-in so you do not need to install it by `pip`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html

Comment: Have you tried using `pip3 install imagescanner` or `python3 -m pip install imagescanner`?  You may be using the python3 version of `pip` instead

Comment: 'python3 -m pip install imagescanner' tells me the command python3 does not exist and pip3 gives me a 'newConnectionError'...

Comment: so what am I supposed to do ? taking the line 'import importlib.util' out doesn't help

Answer (score 2):

`importlib` is builtin with Python 3 (at least for me), you can import it directly without installing anything.

The error from pip install is possibly due to `importlib` is builtin and there's no distribution that's publicly available.

Comment: so the lines of the error are: File "C:\ .....\zipfile.py", in line 9, in <module> import importlib.util --> Import Error: No Module named "importlib.util". What you are saying is that I can leave this line out ?

Comment: So does this mean that with Python 2 `importlib` is not built-in, but needs to be installed via pip?  Is the pip package also called `importlib`?

Answer (score 0):

If your Python is from the last 5 years or so, then `importlib` is builtin. It is available as an external PyPI package for anyone using a much older Python that doesn't have it. You shouldn't be `pip install`ing it, and modules that you are installing also shouldn't be `pip install`ing it. That's a bug in the package you are trying to install, or one of the modules that it installs.