# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.util' in

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install a project I downloaded from github:

```
jlinkels@schrans-pc:/tmp/subsai/src/subsai$ pip3 install -I git+file:///tmp/subsai
Collecting git+file:/tmp/subsai
  Cloning file:///tmp/subsai to /tmp/pip-req-build-8znnvukr
  Running command git clone -q file:///tmp/subsai /tmp/pip-req-build-8znnvukr
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting whisper-timestamped@ git+https://github.com/linto-ai/whisper-timestamped
  Cloning https://github.com/linto-ai/whisper-timestamped to /tmp/pip-install-dk7lxwc1/whisper-timestamped_9286d14b0de04a85a41b274c894ca025
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/linto-ai/whisper-timestamped /tmp/pip-install-dk7lxwc1/whisper-timestamped_9286d14b0de04a85a41b274c894ca025
Collecting openai-whisper<20230124.1,>=20230124
  Using cached openai-whisper-20230124.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
Collecting streamlit-player<0.2.0,>=0.1.5
  Using cached streamlit_player-0.1.5-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)
Collecting pandas<1.6.0,>=1.5.2
  Using cached pandas-1.5.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (12.2 MB)
Collecting importlib<1.1.0,>=1.0.4
  Using cached importlib-1.0.4.zip (7.1 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-dk7lxwc1/importlib_89709f26aefb4b5da3eeb624637ca00e/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-dk7lxwc1/importlib_89709f26aefb4b5da3eeb624637ca00e/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-xff5mn0s
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-dk7lxwc1/importlib_89709f26aefb4b5da3eeb624637ca00e/
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
        import distutils.core
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 16, in <module>
        from distutils.dist import Distribution
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 19, in <module>
        from distutils.util import check_environ, strtobool, rfc822_escape
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/util.py", line 9, in <module>
        import importlib.util
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.util'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/77/3781f65cafe55480b56914def99022a5d2965a4bb269655c89ef2f1de3cd/importlib-1.0.4.zip#sha256=b6ee7066fea66e35f8d0acee24d98006de1a0a8a94a8ce6efe73a9a23c8d9826 (from https://pypi.org/simple/importlib/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement importlib<1.1.0,>=1.0.4 (from subsai)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for importlib<1.1.0,>=1.0.4
```

The installation fails here:

```
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/util.py", line 9, in <module>
        import importlib.util
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.util'
```

importlib is a part from python3.9. So it should not fail.

Indeed, when I start a Python3 shell I can import that module:

```
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import importlib.util
>>>
```

Furthermore, I don't understand this line:

```
Collecting importlib<1.1.0,>=1.0.4
  Using cached importlib-1.0.4.zip (7.1 kB)
```

All other dependencies are in the requirement.txt but not importlib:

```
torch~=1.13.1
openai-whisper~=20230124
streamlit~=1.18.1
streamlit_player~=0.1.5
streamlit-aggrid~=0.3.3
ffsubsync~=0.4.23
git+https://github.com/linto-ai/whisper-timestamped
pandas~=1.5.2
pysubs2~=1.6.0
```

Now it might be relevant that this line:

```
importlib~=1.0.4
```

**was** present in the upstream repository. But installing threw the same error as I still have now.

Update: I also removed any references in pyproject.toml and poetry.lock but I failed to include that in my original post.

Therefore I cloned the project and removed the reference to importlib~=1.0.4 from the requirements.txt.

Why is pip still insisting on installing it. And why does it fail, while it succeeds when I execute the same import in a Python3 shell.

Environment: Debian 11 Bullseye
pip 20.3.4 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.9)
Python 3.9.2

Comment: [The repository](https://github.com/abdeladim-s/subsai) declares dependency [`importlib = ">=1.0.4,<1.1.0"`](https://github.com/abdeladim-s/subsai/blob/2646381643866f317c0eeea40bc95889b74c3f8f/pyproject.toml#L21) in `pyproject.toml`. It also [requires Python 3.10](https://github.com/abdeladim-s/subsai/blob/2646381643866f317c0eeea40bc95889b74c3f8f/pyproject.toml#L14).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48776853/what-is-importlib-util-in-python3 and also: https://github.com/abdeladim-s/subsai/issues/1

Comment: The dependency on `importlib` seems to be a mistake. You can fix it in your own clone of this project.

Comment: @phd I removed any references to importlib from pyproject.toml and poetry.lock. But I did not include that in my post. My bad. I have edited the post accordingly.

Comment: @sinoroc  I saw and studied that post on Stack you are referring to. The issue is identical but has no solution. I created a new post and added more details. The issue on Github is my own post.

Comment: If the external `importlib` is still installed, that may be shadowing the builtin package. It won't be enough to simply remove it from the configuration files; you'll need to remove the installed package and/or create a new virtual environment from the modified configuration.

Comment: It is strange that a project would put a dependency on a stdlib package like importlib. What will happen is that the `importlib` project from pypi.org (a port that exposes 2.7 import functionality for < 2.7 and > 3.0) will be installed. This seems like a really bad idea to me.

Comment: @sinoroc How to remove the dependecies. I grepped thru the complete source tree and removed any reference to importlib. That is why I don't understand it is still being pulled in.

Comment: When you run `pip3 install -I git+file:///tmp/subsai` you ask `pip` to clone from `/tmp/subsai/.git` so it clones pristine `pyproject.toml` and all other files. Instead I think you want to run `pip3 install /tmp/subsai` to use your locally fixed files.

Comment: @JohannesLinkels remove the `importlib` line from the dependencies in `pyproject.toml`, no need to change anything in the actual code.

Comment: @phd I'll make sure to edit, push and clone again to make sure git contains the version I assume it is. and then delete the local repo and re-install. pip install /tmp/subsai fails with a message that no init.py is present and something about a repository being editable, I don't recall exactly. . That is why I use pip install git+file:///my/repo.

Comment: @sinoroc I did but I failed to report that correctly in my original post. As per the comment of phd I will wipe the local repo and retry. See the previous comment.

Comment: @php sinoroc  The issue is solved. The author of the repo made changes in the dependencies in poetry.lock and requirements.txt. Somehow my changes must have contained and error. Or my pip command was incorrect. Anyway, the issue has been solved by removing the depencies. If either one of you would care to post that as an answer I will indicate it as solution. If not, I'll post the solution myself, but I like to give credits to someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to php and sinoroc, they were correct in the statements they made. I am answering the question because I don't want it leave unanswered.

The key problem was dependencies. All references to importlib had to be removed from requirements.txt and pyproject.toml. Which was not too difficult. But then pip kept using the once defined dependencies.

That did not alter the stated dependencies from poetry.lock. The poetry.lock file had to be regenerated in order to use the new settings from pyproject.toml.

In the mean time the author of the project had resolved my issue. I messed up some files and created conflicts in Git. So I only could clone the upstream version again.

I am not 100% sure I reproduced correctly how to solve this, but *I believe* I had to run

```
poetry lock --no-update
```

At least that is how I was able to execute the correct dependencies after changing pyproject.toml

Unfortunately, when I started installing this project I had no clue about the poetry toolkit and was not even aware that it had been used.

The comment by phd not to run

```
pip3 install -I git+file:///tmp/subsai
```

but

```
pip3 install /tmp/subsai
```

for installing from a local repository only also helped.